# python all requests via proxy fail

Tags: python, proxy, python-requests

I'm really out of any ideas what could be the reason for the error...

I'm trying to fetch some info from a site connecting to the site via proxy. All programmatic requests fail whereas their curl counterpart don't.

This is the piece of actual request code:

```
            proxies = {"https": next_ip, "http": next_ip}
            logger.debug(proxies)
            try:
                result: requests.Response = requests.get(
                    url, *args, proxies=proxies, timeout=3, **kwargs
                )
```

args and kwargs are empty...

corresponding log output:

```
r4h.infrastructure.adapter.free_proxy_scrapper:request:67 - {'https': 'https://213.14.32.73:9090', 'http': 'https://213.14.32.73:9090'}
r4h.infrastructure.adapter.free_proxy_scrapper:request:79 - failed for https://213.14.32.73:9090. due to HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.somehost.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /inner/site/url?date=3day (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f09572275e0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused')))
r4h.infrastructure.adapter.free_proxy_scrapper:request:67 - {'https': 'socks4://88.248.14.51:5678', 'http': 'socks4://88.248.14.51:5678'}
r4h.infrastructure.adapter.free_proxy_scrapper:request:79 - failed for socks4://88.248.14.51:5678. due to SOCKSHTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.somehost.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=3)
r4h.infrastructure.adapter.free_proxy_scrapper:request:67 - {'https': 'http://176.235.131.232:9090', 'http': 'http://176.235.131.232:9090'}
r4h.infrastructure.adapter.free_proxy_scrapper:request:79 - failed for http://176.235.131.232:9090. due to HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.somehost.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /inner/site/url?date=3day (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', timeout('timed out')))
r4h.infrastructure.adapter.free_proxy_scrapper:request:67 - {'https': 'socks5://188.132.241.162:56109', 'http': 'socks5://188.132.241.162:56109'}
```

I took random proxies which had an error and tried with `curl` - it's been working :-/

versions of my packages

```
$ pipenv run pip show requests pysocks

Name: requests
Version: 2.26.0
Summary: Python HTTP for Humans.
Home-page: https://requests.readthedocs.io
Author: Kenneth Reitz
Author-email: me@kennethreitz.org
License: Apache 2.0
Location: somepath.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages
Requires: charset-normalizer, urllib3, certifi, idna
Required-by: infi.clickhouse-orm, clickhouse-sqlalchemy
---
Name: PySocks
Version: 1.7.1
Summary: A Python SOCKS client module. See https://github.com/Anorov/PySocks for more information.
Home-page: https://github.com/Anorov/PySocks
Author: Anorov
Author-email: anorov.vorona@gmail.com
License: BSD
Location: somepath.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages
Requires: 
Required-by:
```

Comment: Could it be possible that the site simply blocks proxies?

Comment: then curl wouldn't work as well

Answer (score 0):

As usual the reason is trivial - the target site refuses connections without user agent header...